Show that $\|G_t\ast\phi\|_q\leq \big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2r}}\|\phi\|_p$
Let
\begin{align*}
G_t(x)\,=\, G(x,t)\,=\,(4\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\|x\|^2}{4t}},\ \forall x\in\mathbb R^n,\ t>0.
\end{align*}
I am trying to derive an inequality
\begin{align*}
\ \big\|G_t\ast\phi \big\|_q\leq \big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2r}}\|\phi\|_p\tag1
\end{align*}
where $\displaystyle\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q} $.
I was given a short guidance that : interpolating between $\big\|G_t\ast\phi \big\|_1=\|\phi\|_1$ and the inequality
$\|G_t\ast\phi\|_\infty\leq \big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\|\phi\|_1$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\|G_t\ast\phi\|_q\leq \big(4\pi t\big)^{-\frac{n}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{q} \right) }\|\phi\|_1.\tag2
\end{align}
Interpolating between (2) and  $\big\|G_t\ast\phi \big\|_q\leq\|\phi\|_q$ yields (1).
I still yet to understand the steps that we derive (2), and from there we get (1). I really hope someone would help me to explain it more explicitly. Thanks.

I would look at the proof of Young's inequality

@EvangelopoulosFoivos yes, it would be so simple for anyone by applying Young's inequality for this. What I don't understand is why the author instructed the readers to go around by deriving those inequalities and then interpolating between them to get the final inequality, I just don't get it.
